# filters in Apache HTTP server

Tags: http, filter, apache

I am using Apache HTTP server as a web server in front of WebLogic Application Server. I've integrated these two using mod_wl_22.so plug-in with some configuration in httpd.conf file - now I can access an application deployed on WebLogic Application Server using Apache HTTP Server URL, in other words, the actual URL (WebLogic Application Server URL) to access application localhost:7001/testproj/index.html can be accessed with localhost/testproj/index.html URL (Apache HTTP Server URL) also.

The requirement now is to configure a custom filter (or something), preferably in Java, in Apache HTTP Server so I can modify "form post data" before sending it to WebLogic Application Server. I didn't find any example/help regarding this as of now while googling.

Please let me know if anyone has done this before.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After googling I now have a feeling that Java is not supported in Apache HTTP Server hence I can't write filter (or servlet) in Java. Is this true?

I also found that mod_perl can help me with this problem.