# invoke a Java program in Apache HTTP Server

Tags: java, filter, weblogic, apache

Is there any way to invoke a Java program for a particular URL in Apache HTTP Server? Thanks.

The architecture is like this: Browser > Apache > WebLogic Application Server. My requirement is to invoke a Java code in Apache before request goes to WebLogic Application Server.

Comment: What specifically do you intend this code to do?

Comment: This code will modify post request data which I can't modify at WebLogic end due to design constraint. Thanks.

Comment: Tell us what you **really** want to achieve.

Comment: @ Damian, please follow this URL - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4213045/filters-in-apache-http-server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want to stick with the Java EE Filter solution.  But if, for some reason, you can't do that and absolutely must do this at the Apache layer, Apache does offer filters.   See here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ext_filter.html

Comment: Thanks Jeff. As of now I am using mod_perl2 filter but asked this question if I could do this in Java.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to change some values before a Servlet is invoked, your best option is to implement a Java EE [`Filter`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html), and deploy it at your web app.

There, you can do all the pre-processing you need before invoking your servlet/JSP/WS.

Reference: [The Essentials of Filters](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html)

Comment: I've two questions: 1. How to deploy a JEE application on Apache? 2. How do I invoke this filter for a URL in Apache? Thanks.

Comment: @ankur: 1. you can't. You have to deploy it on a JEE Container, in your case, IBM Websphere. 2. If you check the links, you'll see that the Filter is inside your webapp, and you configure at the web.xml descriptor the paths which the Filter applies. You won't need to redirect the URLs, but when a certain path at your web app is invoked, your Filter will be executed by the container.

Comment: As I mentioned, the post request data needs to change before it reaches to WebLogic Application Server, this won't help. Thanks anyway!

Comment: OK. Then, check Jeff's answer, I think that's right what you need.